# How to edit or set the TLA+ Toolbox Module Modification History Comment syntax or parameters?

Tags: tla+

Am starting my journey exploring TLA+ and more formal software engineering. Am using TLA Toolbox version  `1.6.0`, however, I notice that neither the inbuilt docs, nor the [online docs](https://tla.msr-inria.inria.fr/tlatoolbox/doc/spec/editing-modules.html) offer any hints on how to go about editing or setting the default "Author name" used in the auto-generated modification history log.

For example, on my current machine, the logs take the form below...

```
\* Modification History
\* Last modified Sat Jan 11 12:21:35 EAT 2020 by GAMER
```

That "GAMER" is the string I wish to modify - say, to my initials. However, though you can manually edit that name inline - in the module editor, immediate you save this change, a new modification comment is inserted into the history with the same former mistake!

**How to remedy this?** Some environment variable used? A config file or registry value? I would understand that perhaps it reads the system user info or so, but that's not what I have as my system user name either!

Comment: Under Linux, this is your login name. You could start the toolbox via `USER=someone toolbox`. Not sure about windows though but you could ask in the [tlaplus Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tlaplus) where the developers are participating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./toolbox --launcher.appendVmargs -vmargs -Duser.name=nemesisfixx
```

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: Works well... https://pastebin.com/f2Wg5Nc5 however, noted the toolbox startup time was hell! Slow as hardened molasses :-(

Comment: Please log an issue at https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/issues.